# android how get item by position from RecyclerView extend ListAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, listadapter

I use ListAdapter in my RecyclerView Adpater like below code
question is how can I get item object from my view by it's row position.
I try to write a function in my adapter to get item object by it's position called from view but because I don't have any list in my adapter I can't access it to get it's item object value

```
class QuotesRvAdapter(val mListener : OnQuotesRvListListener):
    ListAdapter<TblQuote, QuotesRvAdapter.ViewHolder>(TaskDiffCallback())
{

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    return ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_quote, parent, false))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(getItem(position),mListener)
}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    fun bind(quote: TblQuote, mListener: OnQuotesRvListListener) {
        itemView.txtQuoteRow.text = quote.toString()
        itemView.ivDeleteRow.setOnClickListener { mListener.onDeleteQuote(quote) }
        itemView.setOnClickListener{ mListener.onPrepareForUpdate(quote) }
    }
}

class TaskDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<TblQuote>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: TblQuote, newItem: TblQuote): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: TblQuote, newItem: TblQuote): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}


interface OnQuotesRvListListener{
    fun onDeleteQuote(ob: TblQuote)
    fun onPrepareForUpdate(ob: TblQuote)
}

}
```

Comment: did you try 'getAdapterPosition()' ?

Comment: yes this method return int position, and I use it, but I want to get the obejct of row by that position, it 's the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method available to access your data object, you have to maintain manually.

```
class QuotesRvAdapter(val mListener : OnQuotesRvListListener):
        ListAdapter<TblQuote, QuotesRvAdapter.ViewHolder>(TaskDiffCallback())

{
    public YourDataClassName getItemData ( int position)
    {
        return getItem(position)

    }


class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

var myDataObj: YourDataClassName;

fun bind(quote: TblQuote, mListener: OnQuotesRvListListener, myData: YourDataClassName) {
        myDataObj = myData;
        itemView.txtQuoteRow.text = quote.toString()
        itemView.ivDeleteRow.setOnClickListener { mListener.onDeleteQuote(quote) }
        itemView.setOnClickListener{ mListener.onPrepareForUpdate(quote) }
}

}


}
```

Comment: I didn't get it , how adding 'myDataObj' variable can help me

Comment: looks like you have used method getItem(position) in adapter class. Make use of it.

Comment: please change your answer just to this comment so I can accept it as answer, thank you

Comment: no need for viewHolder changes, just fun getItemData() do the task, thanks again

Comment: Yes, Initially I misunderstood the question.